# How to find the number of all possible seven-character format license plates?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How can I get the total number of 7-character format license plates (capital letter or digit) if:

**a) There are no further restrictions:**

Number of Capital letters = 26 (A-Z)

Number of Digits = 10 (0-9)

36×35×34×33×32×31×30 = **42072307200**

**b) If the first 3 characters are letters and the last 4 are numbers:**

26×25×24×10×9×8×7 = **78624000**

**c) If letters and numbers alternate, for example A3B5A7Q or 0Z3Q4Q9:**

- Number of permutations that start with a number:

  10×26×9×25×8×24×7 = **78624000**

- Number of permutations that start with a letter:

  26×10×25×9×24×8×23 = **258336000**

- Total number of permutations:

  78624000 + 258336000 = **336960000**

What can be wrong with this approach?

Comment: There are no further restrictions other than they use that character set... wouldn't that mean that a license plate like AE55AEE is allowed?  Your answer seems to assume that characters can't be repeated.  Even in your example in problem c they give an example with two A's in it, implying that characters *can* in fact repeat.

Comment: Have you attempted to revise your answers in light of JMoravitz's comment?